# TableView get next row

Tags: java, javafx

I have table of Audio(My type)
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJBOG.png)

I not understand how get next row after selected

Comment: What do you mean by "get next row"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the currently selected index:

`int ind = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();`

To select the "next row":

```
table.getSelectionModel().select(ind+1);
```

To get the item in the "next row":

```
table.getItems().get(ind+1);
```